# Map from exterior power to the tensor product

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, tensor-products, multilinear-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring such that $2\in R^\times$ and let $M$ be a free $R$-module of finite rank. Let $e_i\wedge e_j$ for $i<j$ be a basis for $\bigwedge^2 M$, and define $\varphi:\bigwedge^2 M\rightarrow M\otimes_R M,\hspace{.5cm}\varphi(e_i\wedge e_j)=\frac{1}{2}(e_i\otimes e_j-e_j\otimes e_i)$. I want to show two things: that this is a homomorphism of $R$-modules, and that for any $m_i,m_j\in M$, $\varphi(m_i\wedge m_j)=\frac{1}{2}(m_i\otimes m_j-m_j\otimes m_i)$.

I have a few questions. To show that it's a homomorphism, does it suffice to show linearity just on the basis elements?

My other confusion is about what the things in the source look like. If the rank of $M$ is $n$, then there are ${n\choose 2}$ pairs of indices such that $1\leq i_1<i_2\leq n$ so an arbitrary element should look like $$\sum\limits_{1\leq i_1<i_2\leq n} a_{i_1i_2} e_{i_1}\wedge e_{i_2}$$ Is this right? I have a related question on the symmetric power, so if someone could provide details on this example it would help a lot with other examples that I'll be trying. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expression for an arbitrary element in $\wedge^2 M$ looks fine to me.

To show linearity, you should note that
$$ \varphi \left( \sum_{1 \leq i_1 < i_2 \leq n} a_{i_1 i_2} e_{i_1} \wedge e_{i_2} \right) =  \sum_{1 \leq i_1 < i_2 \leq n} a_{i_1 i_2}  \varphi\left (  e_{i_1} \wedge e_{i_2} \right)$$
for every possible choice of $a_{i_1 i_2} \in R$. This isn't something you want to show; this should be a part of your definition of $\varphi$.

Now check that this implies linearity, i.e check that this implies that
$$ \varphi( \omega_1 + \omega_2 ) = \varphi(\omega_1) + \varphi(\omega_2)$$
for $\omega_1, \omega_2 \in \wedge^2 M$ and
$$ \varphi( \alpha  \omega ) = \alpha \varphi(\omega) $$
for $\alpha \in R, \omega \in \wedge^2 M$

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. However, how can I see that the formula applies to arbitrary elements of $M$ and not just basis elements?

Comment: Write each $m $ in the form $m = \sum_{i} a_i e_i$. Use the fact that $(a e_i) \wedge e_j = e_i \wedge (a e_j) = a e_i \wedge e_j$ for any $a \in R$.

Comment: Ah, right. Very simple, I was overthinking it.